# SWFUpload with Django 1.2 csrf problem

Tags: django, csrf, swfupload

I`m trying to upload files to Django with  SWFUpload. Found this article [Django with SWFUpload](http://blog.fogtunes.com/2009/11/howto-integrate-swfupload-with-django/). But found one problem. In Django 1.2 a csrf requires a csrf token to be send on every form submit, and it includes files that are send with SWFUpload.So uploading doesnt until i turn off csrf ( globally or for view using @csrf_exempt decorator). Is there a better way to handle this rather than turning off csrf?

I know that i can pass custom data with SWFUpload post_params: {"csrfmiddlewaretoken" : ""},. But i don`t know how to get only value of csrf token in template, not a full input tag.

Comment: I'm using django 1.2 also and I've added csrf token but I'm getting "uploadError: ... HTTP Status: 403". Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the csrf token itself, you'll need to resort to using some of Django's internals. First off, include this line at the top of your view.

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
```

Now, when passing parameters to your template, do something like

```
def my_view(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html", {"csrf_token": get_token(request)})
```

In your template, just reference the token with `{{ csrf_token }}`.